# Database location in solution

Tags: c#, wpf, architecture, prism

I am using C#, WPF and Prism. I want to create modular application, but I have problem. I don't know where to get data from database. This is my solution:

[image: Project Solution]

I have two modules - `ModuleMainFilter` and `ModuleResults`. My original idea was that I would communicate from modules through `Infrastructure` to my database that is currently in `DensoMSBFrontDataClient`. But I cannot do that because I cannot reference `DensoMSBFrontDataClient` in `Infrastructure` due to circular dependency problem. So where I should place my database? I can't come up with any usable idea.

Comment: The question is: why do you have a circular dependency between those two components? Infrastructure sounds like a low level, general package, is shouldn't know about the "higher-ups"...

Comment: Well the modules uses infrastructure to communicate commands and data between each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, here's the layered architecture of your app:

- `DensoMSBFrontDataClient`
- `Modules`
- `Infrastructure`

The `DensoMSBFrontDataClient` references the `*Modules`, which reference the Infrastructure and use this common component as a data exchange. The chain of command goes top-down. Thus should your DB be placed in the lowest layer, and be accessed only from there. Otherwise you will always get some problems of this kind.

Comment: Yes, I used this. This makes most sense and is most usable in my situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you should do is to put your database implementation in it's own module and add an interface implementation to Infrastructure module. The databasemodule should then implement this interface and all modules that consumes the database service should have a reference to Infrastructure and this interface in particular. Take a look at the StockTraderRI and how they have implemented the MarketFeedService.